# How to use 2 ways binding to retrieve [object object] from firebase in Angular 2? [(ngModel)]="product.payload.title"?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

----product.service.ts----

```
export class ProductService {  
  productRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
  product: Observable<any>;

  constructor( private db: AngularFireDatabase ) {  }
  getOne( productId ) {
   this.productRef = this.db.object('/products' + productId);
   return this.product = this.productRef.snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

--- product.component.ts ---

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoriesService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories$ = this.categoriesService.getCategories();
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if ( id ) {
      this.productService.getOne( id ).take( 1 ).subscribe(
      p => this.product = p
    );
   }
  }
}
```

--- product.component.html ---

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)" class="products">
  <div class="form-group"><label for="title">Title</label>
    <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.???.title" name="title"  type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

--- json format database ---

```
{ "payload": { "category": "africa", "imageUrl": "image 01", "price": 12, "title": "test04" }, "type": "value", "prevKey": null, "key": "-KzWO7MPXevJSgLEdKoT" }
```

--- question ---
 How can I display the data from the firebase database for the given id.

Comment: @KENdi not sure why did you place -1 on me? can you tell me please?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you

Comment: sorry, and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like :

`[(ngModel)]="product.payload.title"` but that need to be wrapped b/w `*ngIf='product.payload'`

Like :

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf='product?.payload'>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.payload.title" name="title"  type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

> NOTE : You can't use safe operator ? with 2 way data binding , so
>   there need to be value on the objecy at the time of binding

Comment: @ask.drupal, whats the output of `p => this.product = p` , `p` here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through payload and get the data

declare the variable `product:any = {};`

```
if ( id ) {
  this.product.name = "loading...";
  this.productService.getOne( id ).take( 1 ).subscribe(
  p => {
         p.payload.forEach(product => {
             this.product = product;
         }
     }
);
```

and in your html

```
<input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title"  type="text" class="form-control">
```

you are getting data async, so it will take some time `this.product.name = "loading...";` this will prevent the null value error.

Or you can get the desired data from your `product.service.ts`

```
getOne( productId ) {
   this.productRef = this.db.object('/products' + productId);
   return this.product = this.productRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(action 
=> {
    return { key: action.payload.key, ...action.payload.val() }
 });
}
```

now you can use like this

```
if ( id ) {
    this.product.name = "loading...";
    this.productService.getOne( id ).take( 1 ).subscribe(
    p => this.product = p
  );
```

Comment: method 1(product.component.ts) :  '(product:DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.....
method 2(product.service.ts):  'Subscribtion' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'

Comment: 'Observable<any[]>' should be an array